# Why does light diffract when its light beam from a laser is directed at a hair?

Tags: diffraction

Visible light has a short wavelength of 380-750 nm while a human hair range from 17 to 181µm (https://hypertextbook.com/facts/1999/BrianLey.shtml) what is many times larger that the wavelength of a visible light. Yet, diffraction occurs. Why does this happen? Shouldn't relatively large object be the reason why diffraction does not occur, or am I misunderstanding the concept?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: A hair is thin enough, and the key aspect is that laser light is very **coherent**. Coherence is the key aspect of diffraction. You usually ask for comparable distances because of that: in small distances, the light is still coherent enough to produce diffraction. In larger distances the electric field has lost all correlation.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, @FGSUZ . By coherence you mean that all the light waves have the same direction? And why do we get single slit diffraction, shouldn't it be like two slit diffraction and "slits" would be spaces in left and right of a hair?

Comment: Well, coherence is a fair more complex concepthaha. It has to do with "correlation between electric field at time $t$ and $t+dt$". Search for more info, the concept is well stablished.

Comment: The same diffraction pattern as with a slit, according to Babinet's principle.

Answer (score 1):

You are misunderstanding the concepts in that there are time when diffraction occurs but the viewing conditions are unfavorable.

One way this can happen is that if the fraction of light which is not diffracted is much smaller than that which is diffracted.
Another reason is that each wavelength of light produces a diffraction pattern but there are so many wavelengths and the diffraction patterns overlap a great deal thus obscuring the diffraction patterns.

As an example you can get diffraction due to an edge and a very wide (compared with the wavelength of light) slit.

[image]

I cannot find an edge diffraction image for white light but here is the effect of using white light (many wavelengths) in a double slit demonstration.

[image]

Here you will see the coloured fringes overlapping to give visible fringes close to the centre of the pattern.